# Wikibook API query

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am trying to understand how to build an API call where I can get data (json format) for the recipes, ingredients, and procedure as mention here. Anyone who could help me out with this?

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Recipes

This URL has the recipe names and when clicked on each item it gets the ingredients and the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

To get all recipes I would not use [Cookbook:Recipes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Recipes) but rather [Category:Recipes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Recipes) which is more complete.

The API call to list all recipes which are listed in [Category:Recipes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Recipes) is the following: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Recipes&gcmlimit=max&format=json&gcmcontinue=.
It will return you 500 recipes but there are more on Wikibooks. To get the remaining ones, use the `continue -> gcmcontinue` value in the response and append it to the next API call.

To get the ingredients and procedure of a recipe, call for example
https://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvslots=%2A&rvsection=1&titles=Cookbook:Biscuits.
You can use the `|` character to retrieve multiple recipes with the same API call:
https://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvslots=%2A&titles=Cookbook:Biscuits|Cookbook:Baklava.

If you want to retrieve only the ingredients or only the procedure of recipes, use the additional parameter `rvsection=`. Most of the time (but not always) the ingredients are in the first section and the procedure is the second section. So calling

- https://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvslots=%2A&rvsection=1&titles=Cookbook:Biscuits&rvsection=1 returns you the ingredients for making biscuits and
- https://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvslots=%2A&rvsection=1&titles=Cookbook:Biscuits&rvsection=2 returns you the procedure for making biscuits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was your question, but in addition to Pascalco's answer, it worth note that you will NOT be able to get structured json data that details ingredients with their quantities and procedures, ie something like:

```
{ "ingredient": "milk", "quantity": { "number": "1", "unit":"liter"}}
```

The API will drop the raw mediawiki's syntax page content in one single field, and a few extra metadata about the page.

Moreover, the fact that those pages do not use templates make this type of data very difficult to extract, either with a syntax parser or html parser.